# Audio Problem: In Blender video editor and the rendered file having audio but once I uploaded it to twitter the audio doesn't work

Tags: audio

I was doing video editing on Blender. The frame rate syncs with the audio and I set the audio to be in .mp3 file. In the Blender's video editing the audio works. I also played the rendered file with VLC and it also played the audio too. I dunno the root of the cause but I think it probably has to do with how I setted up the audio :/
[image: The View of Blender]
[image: The setup]

Comment: I would try saving it as MP4 instead of AVI.  If that doesn't work, try uploading it to another service such as youtube or Facebook to make sure it's not just Twitter.  If that works, write it as the answer below so others can benefit.

Comment: thanks! But the video I uploaded WAS on .mp4 format. Can Xvid work?

Comment: Oh ok, sorry, your screenshot says AVI.  I've uploaded multiple MP4's with MP3 audio, 192Kb/s and 384 to youtube.  You might see if you can upload it there and link to it.  No idea why it's not working.

Comment: Alright, I'll try that

Comment: I uploaded it to youtube and it works. I'll link it to twitter now to test it

Comment: IT WORKED!!! Okay, I guess **directly** uploading it won't work so I'll have to **link it** instead. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're very welcome, glad to hear it's working